# Swift: Cannot use library from Pod file

Tags: ios, swift, cocoapods, typhoon

I'm using Typhoon library for Dependency Injection Framework. I use `CocoaPod` for installing this library. Here is my pod file:

```
target "typhoon-swift-demo" do
    pod 'Typhoon'
end

target "typhoon-swift-demoTests" do

end
```

I have installed successfully but when I open workspace project file. I type those line of code as Typhoon sample code:

```
public class ApplicationAssembly: TyphoonAssembly {

}
```

I meet error that my application doesn't recognize `TyphoonAssembly` I have tried to use some lines such as:

```
import Typhoon // not recogize typhoon
import TyphoonAssembly // not regconize
```

Please tell me how to fix this problem. What should I add before I can use library. Thanks :)

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You have to import the Pod header files using Objective-C and not Swift. So you'll be mixing the two languages if you want to use CocoaPods with Swift. [Here's a great tutorial](https://medium.com/@kirualex/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc) on how to accomplish this.

Comment: Nice :D thanks so much :D it costs me amount of time :D just because I want to jump directly into swift before learning anything basic :D

Comment: That one didn't work for me. This one was better http://blog.ios-developers.io/parse-backend-with-swift/

Answer (score 3):

In addition to Quark's answer, [The Typhoon Swift example](https://github.com/typhoon-framework/Typhoon-Swift-Example) shows how to set up Typhoon for usage with Swift and CocoaPods.

Note that if you're using "application-style" tests, which is the default almost everywhere now, then the test target will already implicitly have the main target's dependencies. Therefore the test target should be declared exclusive. Example:

```
platform :ios, '7.0'

target :PocketForecast, :exclusive => true do

  pod 'Typhoon', :head

  pod 'CKUITools'
  pod 'ICLoader'
  pod 'NGAParallaxMotion'
  pod 'NSURL+QueryDictionary'
  pod 'OCLogTemplate'
  pod 'PaperFold', :git => 'https://github.com/jasperblues/PaperFold-for-iOS.git', :tag => '1.2-no-gesture-recognizers'

end

target :PocketForecastTests do
  pod 'Expecta', '~> 0.2.1'
  pod 'OCHamcrest'
  pod 'OCMockito'
end

inhibit_all_warnings!
```

If the test target is not declared exclusive, then it will have all of the application's libraries linked twice. This can cause problems in Typhoon's case, as it uses a lot of introspection.

Also note in the sample application, that there is a bridging header, that includes:

```
#import "Typhoon.h"
```

**Typhoon Swift Example:**

[image]

Comment: thanks :) I have read project's pod file, but I don't understand why author writes that. Now I can understand clearly :D Your library + demo are great, not only for this framework library but also for whom try to learn ios programming :)

Comment: :) Would you be so kind as to add a comment to the Podfile explaining the above, and send a pull request? Seems like we should have included that explanation.

Answer (score 2):

I think this needs an update. I have started recently developping Swift applications and, coming from a Java background, searched for a framework like Spring.
The best I found is Typhoon. I didn't find a good introduction for newbies however, so I made a scratch project to try it out.

I integrated [Typhoon](http://typhoonframework.org) by:

1. Installing [cocoapods](http://guides.cocoapods.org/using/getting-started.html)
2. Creating a basic podfile with a "use_frameworks!" line [like here](https://github.com/appsquickly/Typhoon#dynamic-framework)
3. pod install
4. Adding the "TyphoonInitialAssemblies" array to my plist file
5. Create a first assembly and add it to the array in the plist

In the assembly,

```
import Typhoon

public class MyAssembly:TyphoonAssembly{}
```

Works like a charm!

Answer (score 1):

You have even met this error.

I fixed by way: 
=> remove "platform :ios, 'x.0'"

use_frameworks!
target 'LateManagement' do
    pod 'Alamofire'
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
end