# No such Module 'SwiftyJSON' on Swift 3.0

Tags: swift, xcode, swifty-json, swift3

After migrating to Swift 3.0, I am trying to import SwiftyJSON into my project. However, when I import the framework 'import SwiftyJSON' I get a No Such Module error.

If I remove the import statement, it does not recognize its classes.

Any advice as to why XCode might not be reading my imported framework?

See screenshots attached:

[image]

[image]

[image]

Comment: Did you remove properly the Swift 2 version of SwiftyJSON then installed the Swift 3 version?

Comment: It was a cocoapod, so I commented out the line and reinstalled..

Comment: You may have to "clean your project" (menu Product - Clean) and [delete the derived data](http://stackoverflow.com/a/37793417/2227743).

Answer (score 44):

My problem was I was opening the project file and not the workspace file...

Comment: Silly mistake, but this was my issue too. Thanks for contributing!

Comment: Glad it helped!

Comment: what does that mean ?

Comment: @HosMercury what does what mean?

Comment: @HosMercury it's a file generated by Xcode that is useful for including code in other projects. I am mobile right now and unable to easily provide links or screenshots, but you should see a `.xcworkspace` file in your folder and that should be opened by Xcode

Comment: I made the same mistake. Thanks for the help!

Comment: @ElaineLin Its funny how common this problem is. This is my most upvoted answer and such a simple issue ha

Answer (score 12):

Try to check Targets-> Build Phases Link Binary With Libraries
There must be a link with SwiftyJSON
[image: Check]

Comment: For the ones who are in confusion: this page is not the Build settings of the project, but the "Pods". (blue icon on the navigation menu)

Answer (score 10):

Updating my pod to reference the official SwiftyJSON gem worked for me! It updated from version 2.3.2 (what was installed by default via 'pod SwiftyJSON') to version 3.1.1.

So, in your Podfile, udpate your SwiftyJSON pod to:

```
 pod 'SwiftyJSON', :git =>'https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON.git'
```

HTH

Answer (score 6):

Clean your project and build again. Make sure you open project.xcworkspace.

```
pod 'SwiftyJSON'
```

Comment: pod 'SwiftyJSON' did it for me! But ONLY with the newest version of Cocoapods.

Answer (score 5):

remove `import SwiftyJSON`
to solve `No such Module 'SwiftyJSON' on Swift 3.0`

Swift can load the SwiftyJSON.swift by itself. 
No need to specify it at import statement.

Ref: https://github.com/SwiftyJSON/SwiftyJSON/issues/49

Answer (score 2):

Try this.

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '10.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Project names' do
  pod 'SwiftyJSON', git: 'https://github.com/BaiduHiDeviOS/SwiftyJSON.git', branch: 'swift3'    
end

post_install do |installer|
   installer.pods_project.targets.each do |target|
       target.build_configurations.each do |config|
           config.build_settings['SWIFT_VERSION'] = '3.0'
       end
   end
end
```

Answer (score 1):

If you have multiple targets, try building each of them. I had two targets - one would build and the other would not. This may help you trace the issue.

In my case I just nuked my dev target that was not working, duplicated the production target, made a few settings changes, and was back in action.

Comment: Just letting you know I spent most of the day trying to solve this.  After hours and hours I find your suggestion and it worked.  All I had to do was build the project.  Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

clean your project and than build and run your project and than not work so remove your swiftyjson cocoa library in u r cocoapods and reinstall it should surely work and this 100% work for me ..so u try this.

Answer (score 0):

This solution helped me. Build the modules individually, and then build your project.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/37732248/4899943

Answer (score 0):

//import SwiftyJSON comment out first then
pod install
and  then agian add 
import SwiftyJSON
and pod install 
it work for me

Answer (score 0):

1. In your Xcode project go to podfile and enter :

   ```
    pod 'SwiftyJSON'
   ```
2. Save and close the Xcode.
3. Open terminal and go to project directory and enter :

   ```
    pod install
   ```
4. Open the project and Import `SwiftyJSON` in which file you want to use.