# When i integrate dropbox with pods by using pod i am getting error as SFSafariViewController has no member function using Swift 3

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift3, dropbox-api

I have integrated through pods using  pod 'SwiftyDropbox'  then when i try to execute i am getting error as SFSafariViewController has no member function using Swift 3

```
open class MobileSafariViewController: SFSafariViewController, SFSafariViewControllerDelegate {
    var cancelHandler: (() -> Void) = {}

    public init(url: URL, cancelHandler: @escaping (() -> Void)) {
        if #available(iOS 11.0, *) {
            let config = SFSafariViewController.Configuration()
// (here i am getting error as type SFSafariViewController has no member function)
            config.entersReaderIfAvailable = false
            super.init(url: url, configuration: config)
        } else {
            super.init(url: url, entersReaderIfAvailable: false)
        }

        self.cancelHandler = cancelHandler
        self.delegate = self;
    }
```

Comment: Is that the full error message you're getting? What version of Xcode you're using, and what version of the SwiftyDropbox SDK you have installed?

Comment: I Used Xcode version 8.3.3 and for swiftydropbox i am using latest version, i am even getting    module not found error while i import SwiftyDropbox , can you plzz help me out

Answer (score 1):

This api : `SFSafariViewController.Configuration()` is only available in iOS 11, so it will not compile with Xcode version 8.3.3

https://developer.apple.com/documentation/safariservices/sfsafariviewcontroller.configuration

You can upgrade the Xcode version to Xcode 9 or you can use an older version of SwiftyDropbox.
To do this use this line in your Podfile:

```
pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 4.1.2'
```

Comment: i integrated pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 4.1.2'  getting error no such module SwiftyDropbox

Comment: https://github.com/dropbox/PhotoWatch    When i try the sample i am not getting any error  but when i  immplement it using  pod 'SwiftyDropbox', '~> 4.1.2'  i am getting error as no module found error.

Comment: So you have overcome the first issue. This is a different problem than originally asked. To solve the "no such module" error try the answers in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065447/no-such-module-when-i-use-cocoapods