# 'There is no such module "mobileffmpeg"' when I use CocoaPods

Tags: swift, mobile, import, uikit, cocoapods

**This exact same question was opened, but unfortunately none of the answers there solved my problem.**

**Cocoapods Link :** https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

- XCode Version : 14.2
- Min supported iOS version of the app : iOS 14.0
- macOS Monterey Version 12.7
- Cocoapods Version : 1.13.0

That question is in this link: ['No such module' when I use CocoaPods](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31065447/no-such-module-when-i-use-cocoapods)

**I tried every solution but it didn't help. I am waiting for your useful answers.**

[image: I am using this pod.]

Comment: Which podspec are you using? I don't find it

Comment: You couldn't find it on Cocoapods' own page?

Comment: https://github.com/tanersener/mobile-ffmpeg

Comment: Don't you want to use https://github.com/arthenica/ffmpeg-kit/tree/main/apple which is the recommended version by the author as yours is not supported anymore?

Comment: But on a 2017 MacBook, this library works fine. I am currently using 2020 M1. Why do I have problems on this computer and not on the other?