# When trying to use cocoapods with swift getting error: bridging header does not exist?

Tags: ios, objective-c, xcode, swift, cocoapods

I'm trying to use [this `ExpandingTableView` pod](https://cocoapods.org/pods/ExpandingTableView). When I tried to use it in my project `Expense`, it didn't work, so I looked at [this Stackoverflow post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/26412122/swift-cannot-use-library-from-pod-file) and followed the [linked tutorial.](https://medium.com/@alexiscreuzot/cocoapods-with-swift-e6f8ba8f0afc) Except now I'm getting an error:

```
error: bridging header '/Users/Monica/Documents/CS 4999/Project/Expense/Expense/Expense-Bridging-Header.h' does not exist
```

As part of the tutorial, you are suppose to go into your project's Build Settings and edit the key `Objective-C Bridging Header` to `project_name/project_name-Bridging-Header.h` (in my case: `Expense/Expense-Bridging-Header.h`). And that's what I did [as you can see](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YXnG3.png).

In attempt to fix this error, I edited the key `Objective-C Bridging Header` from `Expense/Expense-Bridging-Header.h` to `Expense/Header.h`, `Expense-Bridging-Header.h`, `Bridging.h`, `./Expense/Bridging.h`, or `./Expense/Expense-Bridging-Header.h`. Nothing solved the error.

If anyone could tell me why this is happening & how to fix this—it would be greatly appreciated!

---

[This is how the files in my project `Expense` are arranged in Xcode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/PdWoy.png)

[These are the files of `ExpandingTableView` pod in Xcode.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/O8OJC.png)

[This is where `Bridging.h` is located on my computer.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/t3N4f.png)

My podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'
# Uncomment this line if you're using Swift
use_frameworks!

target 'Expense' do
pod 'ExpandingTableView'
end

target 'ExpenseTests' do

end

target 'ExpenseUITests' do

end
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you're using frameworks, then you no longer need a bridging header. Instead, you will import the framework directly in the swift file in which you will be using it like so:

```
import ExpandingTableView

class MyTableView: UITableViewController{}
```

Comment: wow I was expecting a much more convoluted intensive solution, but this is so simple! thanks!

Comment: No problem I had to figure this out of myself not too long ago!